# Is it possible to build coo and csr matrices with numpy WITHOUT using scipy?

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have to operate on matrices using an equivalent of sicpy's sparse.coo_matrix and sparse.csr_matrix. However, I cannot use scipy (it is incompatible with the image analysis software I want to use this in). I can, however, use numpy.
Is there an easy way to accomplish what scipy.sparse.coo_matrix and scipy.sparse.csr_matrix do, with numpy only?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The attributes of a `sparse.coo_matrix` are:

```
dtype : dtype
    Data type of the matrix
shape : 2-tuple
    Shape of the matrix
ndim : int
    Number of dimensions (this is always 2)
nnz
    Number of nonzero elements
data
    COO format data array of the matrix
row
    COO format row index array of the matrix
col
    COO format column index array of the matrix
```

The `data`, `row`, `col` arrays are essentially the `data`, `i`, `j` parameters when defined with `coo_matrix((data, (i, j)), [shape=(M, N)])`.  `shape` also comes from the definition.  `dtype` from the `data` array.  `nzz` as first approximation is the length of `data` (not accounting for zeros and duplicate coordinates).

So it is easy to construct a `coo` like object.  Similarly a `lil` matrix has 2 lists of lists.  And a `dok` matrix is a dictionary (see its `.__class__.__mro__`).

The data structure of a `csr` matrix is a bit more obscure:

```
data
    CSR format data array of the matrix
indices
    CSR format index array of the matrix
indptr
    CSR format index pointer array of the matrix
```

It still has 3 arrays.  And they can be derived from the `coo` arrays.  But doing so with pure Python code won't be nearly as fast as the compiled `scipy` functions.

But these classes have a lot of functionality that would require a lot of work to duplicate.  Some is pure Python, but critical pieces are compiled for speed.  Particularly important are the mathematical operations that the `csr_matrix` implements, such as matrix multiplication.

Replicating the data structures for temporary storage is one thing; replicating the functionality is quite another.